# 3 Monitors on Fedora

Tags: xorg, monitors, multi-monitor

I just got a new TV and I want it to be a 2nd secondary display, however it will only allow me to turn on 2 monitors at any given time. How can I make it allow me to use an arbitary number of monitors?

[image: My Displays]

As secondary monitors.

I am running these monitors using nvidia 630, and they are connected as follows.

```
HDMI -> Sceptre
VGA -> 1 ACER
DVI -> VGA -> OTHER ACER
```

Comment: How are you connecting these, and to what graphics card? Are you sure that it can handle driving three displays simultaneously?

Comment: @mattdm Updated question with requested information. I am totally sure that the graphics card is capable of this.

Answer (score 1):

xrandr is your friend. You are going to need to know the official names of the outputs that Linux supports for your hardware, and "xrandr -q" can report those.

Here's an example of a script I wrote that I run when I want to switch to a 3-display configuration (this is very specific to my hardware and display layout, but you should be able to adapt to your situation easily).

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --output eDP1 --primary --crtc 0 --mode 1920x1080
sleep 1
xrandr --output DP1-2 --crtc 2 --right-of eDP1 --mode 2560x1440
sleep 1
xrandr --output DP1-1 --crtc 1 --right-of DP1-2--mode 2560x1440
```

The reason I don't try to do it all at once, and have the sleeps interspersed, is because my graphics adapter gets confused if I try to configure too many crtcs at once.